# cygwin: ssh identity file not accessible

Tags: ssh, windows-10, cygwin

I am new to cygwin. I have problems to use ssh there.

When I try using it I get the following error:

```
$ ssh -i /home/Sebastian/.ssh/id_rsa user@domain
Warning: Identity file /home/Sebastian/.ssh/id_rsa not accessible: No such file or directory.
user@domain: Permission denied (publickey).
```

permissions are set as following:

```
drwx------+ 1 Sebastian Kein 0 Dec 31 15:06 /home/Sebastian/.ssh
-rw------- 1 Sebastian Kein 1766 Oct 11 22:24 /home/Sebastian/.ssh/id_rsa
```

I mounted `/` to `C:\programs\cygwin64`

part 2, I added some changes:

I removed all world and group permissions on id_rsa in Windows 10

The following works now:

```
> ssh -i .ssh/id_rsa user@domain
```

Any other way to access the id_rsa file fails (/home/Sebastian/.ssh/id_rsa or ~/.ssh/id_rsa) for example. Neither does rsync with ssh work

Does anyone have an idea whats wrong here?

Comment: I found one solution. I added the ssh file to `C:\\Users\\Sebastian/.ssh/id_rsa` in Windows. This is loaded magically in cygwin (without specifying any shh private key file) .... Howver rsync does not work with this trick

Answer (score 0):

The plus in `drwx------+` suggests there is extended ACL.

What you can try is to do a backup of /etc/fstab, then change the line to :

```
none /cygdrive cygdrive binary,noacl,posix=0,user 0 0
```

and restart Windows and try ssh again.

Comment: Hi Phillipe. Thank you for the idea. Unfortunately this doesn't change anything (neither the + dissapears, nor ssh gets any better)

Comment: What do you get if you type `type ssh` ? Are you using Windows version of `ssh` ?

Comment: $ type ssh
ssh is hashed (/cygdrive/c/Windows/System32/OpenSSH/ssh)

Comment: I am not sure what I am using. I just installed cygwin and use it out of the box

Comment: However see above, I found a solution for ssh

Comment: I'd recommend you use cygwin's ssh. run `echo $PATH` and make sure `/usr/bin` is before `/cygdrive/c/Windows/System32/OpenSSH`

Comment: That was a great tip. Thank you. Actually, the $PATH variable was correct, but openssh was not installed. Now it works like a charm!

Comment: @Philippe - excellent answer - that was my problem.  Thanks.

Comment: @staggart Glad my answer helped, maybe you can give an upvote.